# How can I enable the deep RC6 sleep states on an haswell architecture?

Tags: energy-saving, haswell

If you use `iotop`you will see three sleep states. One is called RC6 and the other two are deep sleep states called  RC6p and RC6pp. I read the modinfo i915 and saw that one can enable them by passing enable_rc6=7 to the kernel.

> parm:           enable_rc6:Enable power-saving render C-state 6.
>   Different stages can be selected via bitmask values (0 = disable; 1 =
>   enable rc6; 2 = enable deep rc6; 4 = enable deepest rc6). For example,
>   3 would enable rc6 and deep rc6, and 7 would enable everything.
>   default: -1 (use per-chip default) (int)

But after a reboot I recognized that only RC6 is enabled. I passed this param via the kernel command line and via modprobe.d, but non of them worked. So how can I enable these deep states?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple answer is you can't. Those sleep states have been abandoned, since the haswell architecture. There is only RC6 left. See [here](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/4th-gen-core-family-desktop-vol-1-datasheet.pdf) or [here](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/intel-gfx/2012-June/018383.html).